# Data transition for the external page - Jquery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

How to Link the external pages in Jquery Mobile to make the Data transition work?

```
<a href="appleave.html" rel="external" data-transition="slide"><img
                src="images/image.png" alt="NoImage" /></a>
```

Transition is not working in the above code. Help me guys..

Comment: Can you provide the markup for your source and destination pages?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do here, official documentation states that:

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false")
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external"
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior.

Here's the official [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html); search for: **Linking without Ajax**

Do you really need **rel="external"**? Because page is not loaded into the DOM jQM can not create a transition effect.

Comment: External Page is not loading properly without rel="external".. So I should not link the page externally If I want the Data transition to work?

Comment: If you don't have any problems loading it to DOm with ajax then remove rel="external" and transitions will work, in any other case you will need to work without them.

Comment: If I remove the rel="external" -> <a href="appleave.html"  data-transition="slide"><img
                src="images/image.png" alt="NoImage" /></a>.. The appleave.html is not loading properly.. Can u pls help me with how can I load it to DOM with Ajax?

Comment: Do u mean something like this? http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Comment: Yes but you will also need to initialize this in mobileinit event: $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; 
});

Answer (score 0):

Do u have added `<script src="Your JQuery Mobile js file path"></script>` in `<head>` tag of `<html>`.

Comment: Yes Yes.. I have added all the css and js files